# How to define new attributes of an endpoint in WSO2 G-REG?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am evaluating WSO2 G-REG and would like to add additional attributes to end points (that I initially intend to use for documentation purposes and later on for automation).

I do for instance have one (or possible multiple) "native" endpoint that the service is deployed with in container(s) and in addition to them several "virtualized" endpoints for instance in other network segments (WAN, DMZ...) created by XML gateways and "wired to" the native endpoint(s).

To support this I would like attributes that allow me to specify things like network segment and what "native endpoint(s)" that a "virtual endpoint" is "wired to" etc.

What part of the documentation covers this? Do anybody have some XML snippet that shows how to do it?

I would later like to try adding automation that pushes information to the right Gateway to create the virtual endpoints (perhaps tied to a special like cycle stage transition)... but that is a later challenge...

Answer (score 0):

Endpoints are managed by a handler (org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.EndpointMediaTypeHandler). If you want to add custom attributes, you will have to extend [this](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/carbon/3.2.0/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions/3.2.3/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/registry/extensions/handlers/EndpointMediaTypeHandler.java) with your own.

Thanks,
Senaka.